# How to use "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" on pre-honeycomb devices?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-3.0-honeycomb

### Background

i need to start an activity on certain events (like a notification click, but it can be any other event, even from a broadcastReceiver) that will also close all other activities if they were running, or at least don't give focus to them.

for this, i use [**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) flag.

### The problem

it seems that Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag only works on **API 11** (honeycomb) and above .

some websites have claims that [**IntentCompat**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html) could help , but even there the documentation specifically says :

> This flag will only be obeyed on devices supporting API 11 or higher.

sadly i can't find any examples of using the IntentCompat functions, and the descriptions is as vague and confusing as the intents flags documentations

### The question

how can i overcome this problem?

should i really add a [**LocalBroadcastManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) for each of the activities to listen to this event, and close themselves in case it occurs ?

Maybe I'm missing something here? What are the other functions that are shown on the IntentCompat class ? maybe one of them could help with this?

Please help.

---

EDIT:
It seems that [**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) does the job of not-focusing on the previous activities, but the documentation has a very vague description of how it works, and it also has a lot of warnings about it .

what i've noticed is that even if we close the new activity, the previous task of the app won't take focus, so it will go back to where the user has visited before.

does anyone know how this flag works, and what should i know about it? is it safe to be used in such cases ?

if i won't find any other solution, i think i will add it as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
       intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

Or You could also use BroadcastReciver in all of your activities..

```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     private FinishReceiver finishReceiver;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finishReceiver = new FinishReceiver();
    registerReceiver(finishReceiver,
            IntentFilter.create("Finish", "XYZ"));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
  }

   private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
  }
 }
```

For clearing the stack:

```
           Intent intent = new Intent("Finish");
           intent.setType("XYZ");
           sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Adding a broadcast to all activities is really a poor solution if you care about quality code..